# Remove duplicates from a list (in vim)

Tags: list, vim, double, duplicates

This is my list:

```
['02', '03', '03', '16', '17', '17', '28', '29', '29']
```

I would like to know how I can remove the duplicates from this list.

Would it be also possible when I add an item to the list to check 
if the item is already in the list (to avoid duplicates?)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean removing duplicate lines in VIM?

Comment: sorry, no from an array in vimscript

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
let list=['02', '03', '03', '16', '17', '17', '28', '29', '29']
let unduplist=filter(copy(list), 'index(list, v:val, v:key+1)==-1')
```

. For the second question, see `:h index()`.

By the way, if

1. all list items are strings;
2. there is no empty strings possible;
3. you don't care about order of list items

then you should probably use a Dictionary instead: for large number of strings searching for duplicates is faster (and really not required).

Answer (score 4):

This ex-mode (i.e. enter after `:`) regex substitution will eliminate the duplicates (provided they are consecutive):

```
s/\('[0-9]\+'\),\s\+\1/\1/g
```

Comment: gotta love vim and all its subtleties

Answer (score 3):

You could also convert the list to the keys in a Dictionary:

```
let list=['02', '03', '03', '16', '17', '17', '28', '29', '29']
let dict = {}
for l in list
   let dict[l] = ''
endfor
let uniqueList = keys(dict)
```

This works for both sorted and unsorted lists.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Vim 7.4.218 (25 Mar 2014) and newer](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.218)

provides

```
uniq({list} [, {func} [, {dict}]])          *uniq()* *E882*
        Remove second and succeeding copies of repeated adjacent
        {list} items in-place.  Returns {list}.  If you want a list
        to remain unmodified make a copy first: >
            :let newlist = uniq(copy(mylist))
<       The default compare function uses the string representation of
        each item.  For the use of {func} and {dict} see |sort()|.
```

Comment: It only removes repeating adjacent elements, it doesn't make it unique, for example `uniq([1, 1])` returns `[1]` but `uniq([1, 2, 1])` returns `[1, 2, 1]`.

Comment: `sort()` first and duplicates will be adjacent, then `uniq()` will take care of deduplicating them. Example: `uniq(sort([1, 2, 1]))`

Comment: @PeterBenjamin Unfortunately, if you the order needs to be preserved, sorting first isn't viable. Something to keep in mind for those who can't sort their list before deduping.